# Nested list from string separated by spaces and brackets

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

Hello I'm trying to obtain a list with other ones nested in it. 
This is the string I have:

```
'"Title" "Title  of  an  article,  chapter,  etc." ("The Divine Comedy" "Rules of Construction") true null null false'
```

This is the result I'm trying to achieve:

```
['Title', 'Title of an article, chapter, etc.', ['The Divine Comedy', 'Rules of Construction'], true, null, null, false]
```

I'm currently using `shlex, but with no success:

```
def metadata():
    md = shlex.split(content)
    print md
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recursive call to [re.findall](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) might do the trick. You need to chose your regex pattern judiciously

```
>>> st = '"Title" "Title  of  an  article,  chapter,  etc." ("The Divine Comedy" "Rules of Construction") true null null false'
>>> def nest_split(st):
    return [nest_split(e[1:-1]) if e.startswith('(') else e.strip('"') for e in re.findall("\(.*?\)|\".*?\"|\w+", st)]

>>> nest_split(st)
['Title', 'Title  of  an  article,  chapter,  etc.', ['The Divine Comedy', 'Rules of Construction'], 'true', 'null', 'null', 'false']
```

**Note** `true`, `false` and `null` are not valid Python identifiers so would be treated as string